# What did the broadcast mentioned in the opening crawl say?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, the opening crawl establishes that there has been a radio broadcast in the voice of

> Emperor Palpatine, declaring revenge against the Resistance. The exact contents of it are not described in the film.

What specifically did the broadcast say?

Comment: The dead speak!

Comment: It said "I'm not dead yet. I might recover"

Comment: It said *"I could conquer the whole galaxy in a surprise attack, but instead I tell it to everyone when I will attack, so they have time to prepare and so they can stop me while my fleet is still docked and vulnerable"*.  :)

Comment: Overconfidence was always Palpatine's weakness, as Luke observed long ago in RotJ.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The broadcast was exclusively revealed during Fortnite's Rise of Skywalker event. It said:

> At last the work of generations is complete. The great error is corrected. The day of victory is at hand. The day of revenge. The day of the Sith!

Source for quote is the image with the broadcast subtitled in this article: https://www.businessinsider.com/screenshots-inside-fortnite-star-wars-rise-of-skywalker-preview-event-2019-12

Comment: I didn't see anything in the article suggesting that the message in the Fortnite game was meant to be same one referred to in the opening crawl.

Comment: This is confirmed in the _Rise of Skywalker_ novelization.

Comment: “You might call it the ‘Revenge of the Sith’, although I think we used that already!”