# Why didn't the Rebels know about the Palpatine transmission?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker, the-rebel-alliance

The opening crawl of ROS makes it clear a transmission *has already been made*.

> The dead speak! The galaxy has heard a mysterious broadcast, a threat of revenge in the sinister voice of the late Emperor Palpatine.

Yet Poe Dameron and all the Rebellion leadership seems caught by surprise when the traitor's information tells them that. [From the transcript](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IX:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker)

> REY: What's the message?
>
> POE: We’ve decoded the intel from the First Order spy.... and it confirms the worst. (sighs) Somehow, Palpatine returned.
>
> [All gasp, murmuring]
>
> ROSE: Wait. Do we believe this?
>
> AFTAB: It cannot be. The Emperor's dead.

Why didn't anyone there seem to know about [Palpatine's transmission](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224780/what-did-the-broadcast-mentioned-in-the-opening-crawl-say)?

Comment: Because they're too busy plotting against the Empire to be playing Fortnite

Comment: The information from the spy *confirms* that Palpatine is really back and that the transmission wasn't faked by the First Order, is what I thought they were saying. I mean you can edit dialogue from dead actors into coherent sentences in real life, so faking a message from Palpatine wouldn't be impossible.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Yeah but (ignoring the sloppy storywriting and moon-sized-battlestation plot holes) I would have expected someone to mention that either way, which nobody does. The entire scene implies they're just now finding this out

Comment: @Machavity Fair enough. Which is why I didn't give that as an actual answer.

Comment: I agree with SpaceWolf... the new intel is confirming the transmission is real. If they didn't know about the transmission at all there would be nothing to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) confirms that they absolutely did know about the transmission. The confirmation they were getting (via their spy) was that the message *wasn't faked*.

> Poe addressed the group. “Thanks to See-Threepio and Beaumont, we’ve decoded the intel from the First Order spy, and it confirms the worst.” He waited a moment, as though reluctant to continue. After a deep breath, he added, “Somehow, Palpatine has returned.”
>
> Rey gasped along with everyone else.
>
> Rose frowned. “Wait…do we believe this?”
>
> **Rey thought of the transmission that had flooded the galaxy, remembered her own dark visions. “We believe it,” she said.**
>
> Aftab Ackbar was shaking his head. “It cannot be. The Emperor is dead,” he insisted. “Killed aboard the second Death Star.”